# How to repeat ArrayList as randomly Indexes in the kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, arraylist

As you read the title i want to repeat `ArrayList` index by index as randomly each time.

I tried build code of `kotlin` like this:

```
fun randomlyNumber(a:IntRange=1..10) = a.random()
val arr: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
```

And i create `additional` function:

```
fun additional():ArrayList<String>{
    for (ss in 0..randomlyNumber()){
        arr.add("0")
    }
     return arr
}
```

This function will add `0` value to the `arr` each roll in the `additional` function, And as you see number of rolls is randomly.

And `additional2`  function to print each index in `arr` `ArrayList` as alone, and complete the ellipse in `arr` (the indexes) by number `1` until 10 (max index).

```
var int =0

fun additional2(){
    additional()
    for (ss in 1..10){
        for (cc in arr.size..10){
            arr.add("1")
        }
        println(arr[int])
        int++
        if (int==10)int=0
    }
}
```

The main fun:

```
fun main() {
    for (ss in 1..5){
        additional2()
        println("------------")
    }
}
```

Run:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
------------
 x5 times
```

And this the whole issue, the code repeat the forms of `arr` as same 5 times, but i want 5 different forms as randomly from the `arr` in the same Run.

Note: If i Run it another time it will gave me different form 5 times.

Sorry about bad English it's my second language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `arr` object globally, which gets reused for each of the five iterations. Instead you should be initializing the Arraylist in `additional` function

```
fun additional():ArrayList<String> {
    val arr: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList() 
    for (ss in 0..randomlyNumber()){
        arr.add("0")
    }
     return arr
}
```

And use the same arraylist in the second function

```
fun additional2(){
    var int = 0
    val arr = additional()
    for (ss in 1..10){
        for (cc in arr.size..10){
            arr.add("1")
        }
        println(arr[int])
        int++
        if (int==10)int=0
    }
}
```

The whole code can simplified as

```
fun additional() {
    val arr = (0..randomlyNumber()).map { "0" }
    val x = arr + (arr.size..10).map { "1" }
    println(x)
}
```